# button-group in horizontal and vertical

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, buttongroup

I want resposive view of buttons in bootstrap. Like that:

```
[button1] [button3] [button5]
[button2] [button4] [button6]
```

and on phone:

```
[button1]
[button2]
[button3]
[button4]
[button5]
[button6]
```

As user clicked in one button it should be set to active, others inactive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one http://jsbin.com/dohanivo/1 , in that example I used 4 column for lg,md and sm and 12 column for xs devices.

Comment: That does not appear to be a button-group. Just some buttons in a grid